# Creating WSO2 Multi Module Maven Project without Eclipse

Tags: maven, wso2

The WSO2 Developer Studio plugin for Eclipse has a wizard
for generating a Multi Module Maven project. Is there any way
to create a project like this with Maven from the command line?
And is it possible also with other project types like ESB Config,
Composite Application Project, Registry Resources Project, etc.?

Thanks,
B.

Comment: check for archetypes ...

Comment: You should be able to create projects using related archetypes. But I don't think it will help when you creating the ESB config and other types of resources. Developer studio supports creating these type of artifacts with design and source view (for ESB).

Comment: Rans, I have come up with ways to do everything else (adding mediators and other artifacts) without the use of Eclipse and Developer Studio. The only thing I can't get is how to create an empty project with just Maven. I'm not sure how to find the necessary archetypes.